# How to do an enum in xml

Tags: xml, enums, wsdl

I have a number of request types - which really are enums.

But in my code these request types are an enum:

```
enum RequestType {
  RequestRegister,
  RequestUnregister,
  etc
};
```

My current attempt at a wsdl file is below.  But it uses a string type.  In my server I need to extract an enum/int from the xml.  Doing lookups on a string seems like bad design.

So how do I form my wsdl file so that the request types are enums?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="CubaCTI"
targetNamespace="http://www.iteloffice.com/wsdl/cubacti.wsdl"
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:tns="http://www.iteloffice.com/wsdl/cubacti.wsdl"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<message name="MonitorStartRequest">
 <part name="user_name" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="dn" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="MonitorStartResponse">
 <part name="errorcode" type="xsd:short"/>
 <part name="errormessage" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<message name="MonitorStopRequest">
 <part name="user_name" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="dn" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="MonitorStopResponse">
 <part name="errorcode" type="xsd:short"/>
 <part name="errormessage" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<message name="MakeCallRequest">
 <part name="user_name" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="dn" type="xsd:string"/>
 <part name="destination" type="xsd:string"/>
 <part name="userdata" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="MakeCallResponse">
 <part name="errorcode" type="xsd:short"/>
 <part name="errormessage" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<message name="ClearConnectionRequest">
 <part name="user_name" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
 <part name="dn" type="xsd:string"/>
 <part name="destinationconnectionid" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="ClearConnectionResponse">
 <part name="errorcode" type="xsd:short"/>
 <part name="errormessage" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<portType name="CubaCTIRequests">
  <operation name="MonitorStart">
     <input message="tns:MonitorStartRequest"/>
     <output message="tns:MonitorStartResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="MonitorStop">
     <input message="tns:MonitorStopRequest"/>
     <output message="tns:MonitorStopResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="MakeCall">
     <input message="tns:MakeCallRequest"/>
     <output message="tns:MakeCallResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="ClearConnection">
     <input message="tns:ClearConnectionRequest"/>
     <output message="tns:ClearConnectionResponse"/>
  </operation>

</portType>

<binding type="tns:CubaCTIRequests" name="cubactibinding">
 <soap:binding style="document"
       transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

 <operation name="MonitorStart">
   <soap:operation soapAction="MonitorStart"/>
   <input>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </input>
   <output>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </output>
 </operation>

 <operation name="MonitorStop">
   <soap:operation soapAction="MonitorStop"/>
   <input>
      <soap:body
           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
           namespace="http://www.iteloffice.com/cubctirequests"
           use="encoded"/>
   </input>
   <output>
      <soap:body
           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
           namespace="http://www.iteloffice.com/cubctirequests"
           use="literal"/>
   </output>
 </operation>

 <operation name="MakeCall">
   <soap:operation soapAction="MakeCall"/>
   <input>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </input>
   <output>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </output>
 </operation>

 <operation name="ClearConnection">
   <soap:operation soapAction="ClearConnection"/>
   <input>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </input>
   <output>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </output>
 </operation>


</binding>


<service name="CubaCTI_Service">
  <documentation>WSDL File for Cuba CTI services</documentation>
   <port binding="tns:cubactibinding" name="CubaCTIRequestsBinding">
     <soap:address 
        location="http://angusnotebook:8080"/>
   </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

Additional note.

I am 'forced' to use xml because the client can only send xml messages (no control over this).  But I make up the xml that the client uses.  The server, which I have control of/write is written in C++ and I am using libxml to extract the 'parts' of the xml file.  Ideally the item would be an int or enum.  Because I want to eg do this:

//extract item from xml - into an enum or int
   RequestType rqtype = getRequestType();

```
switch(rqtype) {
 case RequestMakeCall:
  //do whatever
```

In the above case RequestType is an enum.  It is not efficient to extract a string value and then have to do a lookup of the related enum value.

All the examples I see of enums seem to use strings, which seems odd.

Comment: I think representing strings as enums is much more natural. It makes the XML and the parsing code more readable. And any performance differences probably won't matter – the library and your parsing code already has to work with strings, so a little more of that won't hurt. If the speed of reading the values is important for you, don't use XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own types:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://www.iteloffice.com/wsdl/cubacti.wsdl"
             xmlns:tns="Mediaresearch.SimNet.Communication" 
             xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
              targetNamespace="http://www.iteloffice.com/wsdl/cubacti.wsdl">
      <s:simpleType name="OperatingSystemVersion">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="None" />
          <s:enumeration value="WinXp" />
          <s:enumeration value="WinVista" />
          <s:enumeration value="Win7" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
    </s:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="OperatingSystemVersion">
    <part name="user_name" type="tns:OperatingSystemVersion" />
  </message>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Probably I am a little confused with restriction base being string. Does restriction base="string" just mean the name of the enum is a string?  All names would be strings?   In my receiver code I use libxml.  My concern I suppose is how libxml will extract the OperatingSystemVersion?  Do I need to be looking at how libxml copes with enum values?

Comment: the `<s:resctrictions>` says something like: the type is a string, but with those additional restrictions. Yeah, pretty much is says that the name is a string. I have no idea what would you need to do in libxml, I have never worked with it.

Comment: Be careful when specifying part elements by type instead of element attributes. That leaves the namespace of the parent node unspecified (in contrast with the node's child elements which are qualified correctly), leaving its namespace definition open to interpretation, which could lead to interoperability problems.